# bringing up calendar picker in input <type=date> with Selenium/Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, datepicker, action

I have to test this date picker using Java and Selenium.  See picture.  The non yellow-highlighted part is where you put the date text, and the yellow part, when you click on it, brings up a date picker.

My problem is the whole field is just one input, and the only line inside a div:

```
 <div class="term_dateWidth__hL6-b" style="visibility: visible;">
    <input type="date" id="start" min="1900-01-01" max="9999-12-30" value="">
 </div>
```

I can find the element but when I click it it only highlights the text box and does not bring up the picker.  If I manually click on that highlighted part with the mouse it will bring it up.  I just can't figure out how to do it with Selenium.  I even tried the parent div but that did not work.

I though maybe with Actions I could go to a point but that didn't seem to work either, though maybe I don't understand using dimensions correctly. Element *termDateArrow* has already been set to the input below.

```
public void clickTermDateArrow() {
    Dimension size = termDateArrow.getSize();
    int height = size.getHeight();
    int width = size.getWidth();
    Point point = termDateArrow.getLocation();
    int x = point.getX();
    int y = point.getY();
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(termDateArrow, width - 1, y + 10).build().perform();
}
```

but that doesn't work either.  I am trying to click an offset from the top left point (which getLocation() works. And yes I know I can send text to the box but that does not test the picker.

Any suggestions?  See image

[image]

Comment: Please, provide a [MCVE]

Comment: you'll probably want to use offets with moveToElement when doing the click.  So get the element, then use Actions to click it with an offset of  0, +x number of pixels: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#moveToElement(org.openqa.selenium.WebElement,int,int)  You'll be starting at the middle of the element... you can get the element's width with the .getSize() method... offset a little less than half the width.  Note that these controls are browser-specific so you may need to branch code per browser.

Comment: I ended up doing this.  Not sure how to fix the formatting.  Better still, see solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this

```
    Dimension size = termDateArrow.getSize();
    int width = size.getWidth();
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);

    action.moveToElement(termDateArrow, (width / 2) - 5, 0).build().perform();
    action.click().build().perform();
    TestUtils.sleep(5000);
```

for some reason I had o click twice.  Unfortunately, it appears to be a Windows calendar picker so Selenium can't find it.  I just hit ENTER and verify the date is the current date